# Overhead effect in Iterative Deepening by increasing branching factor and depth

Tags: artificial-intelligence, iterative-deepening

I am studying Iterative Deepening from this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search). My main concern is with **Overhead**. That link says that

> The higher the branching factor, the lower the overhead of repeatedly
>   expanded states

There is no explanation given for this statement and also no convincing arguments are given at that link. I am searching the reason behind this statement because I think that overhead should increase as branching factor is increasing and it also means that no of nodes are increasing then how overhead is reducing?

Till now I did not find anything reasonable and helpful. If someone can help in correcting my concepts then I would be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is in the formula above the statement

```
 (d)b + (d-1)b^{2} + \cdots + 3b^{d-2} + 2b^{d-1} + b^{d}
```

The cost of doing a BFS - which is to what you should compare is --

```
 b + b^{2} + \cdots + b^{d-2} + b^{d-1} + b^{d}
```

Hence the overhead is

```
   (d-1)b + (d-2)b^{2} + \cdots + 2b^{d-2} + 1b^{d-1}
```

Obviously this is heavily influence by the branching factor. especially when looking at the last term `1b^{d-1}`

Comment: You said, "Obviously this is heavily influence by the branching factor", does it means overhead increases with increase in branching factor?

Comment: yes if the solution is in the second level of the search it is grow quadratic, third level cubic,.... This is kind of disastrous, however, the algorithms run time runs `b-times` that fast, hence, the overhead is clearly dominated